Why did I get suspended from reviews?
I just got suspended from reviews because the system flagged that I reviewed this question incorrectly:https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/35942786
I believe I made the right call because I downvoted the post. After all, the question isn't in line with the Stack Overflow's question guideline.
I would like to know what choice I should have made and why?

Review suspensions come from failing multiple audits; that was an audit, and the question was deleted.

That question is about a mile off topic and you should have selected one of the close reasons along with downvoting it. I can't speak for the server, but I would have accepted Not about programming or Seeking recommendations as good close reasons.

Moderators in the case of incorrect review decisions will take action. In this specific case it was an audit, and again a review suspension, is the result of multiple incidents of incorrect decisions
